# Get a Bootstrap button dropdown to remain open from the outset (on page load)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this code using Bootstrap 3:

```
<button class="btn btn-runs btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button">20 checklist runs in progress <i class="glyphicons download"></i></button>
<ul class="dropdown-runs" role="menu"><li> ... </li></ul>
```

On clicking the button, a list opens fine. However, I want the list to be open on page load, from the outset. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving it the `.open` class.

For example, `<div class="dropdown open">`

Source: Found it in the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Aaron but if that does not work. Try giving it a unique id and use some jquery to simulate a click.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dropdown_id").click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try toggling using JS...

```
$('my-selector').dropdown('toggle')
```

Answer (score 0):

Place it inside a `btn-group` with `open`..

```
<div class="btn-group open">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    20 checklist runs in progress
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>..</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/5aXZWb6XjG